# "unrecognized expression node array index linq" exception in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my LINQ in which I comparing a DateTime type of field with current date-

```
 var srs = (from s in dcDistrict.ScheduledReportStatus
            where s.ReportConfigId.Equals(ConfigId)
            && s.Status.HasValue && s.Status.Value
            && (Convert.ToString(s.SentDate).Split(' ')[0]).Equals(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Date).Split(' ')[0])
            select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

this code is giving the excpetion "unrecognized expression node array index linq", Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't you just compare the date's Year? Is there any justification to converting them to strings?

Comment: Are you actually trying to compare the year, or something else? (The behaviour of `Convert.ToString(DateTime)` depends on the culture - we don't know what you're expecting to achieve.)

Comment: I'm only comparing today's date.

Comment: My column is of DateTime type and I only want to compare Date. That's why to get only Date from the Datetime I'm splitting the column.

Comment: Then why don't you compare SentDate.Date == DateTime.Today(.Date)?

Comment: I'm not getting the property .Date with my column name in intellicense.

Comment: What type is `SentDate` then?

Comment: As I said its of Datetime type

Comment: Have you tried `Substring` instead of `Split`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution, what I need to do is to use "AsEnumerable()", Here is the resolved version of my LINQ-

```
 Var srs = (from s in dcDistrict.ScheduledReportStatus.AsEnumerable()
                                         where s.ReportConfigId.Equals(ConfigId)
                                         && s.Status.HasValue && s.Status.Value
                                         && (Convert.ToString(s.SentDate).Split(' ')[0]).Equals(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Date).Split(' ')[0])
                                         select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

AsEnumerable() done some part of the code client side that resolves my issue.

Comment: Don't do that. It will bring the entire table into application and perform filtering as linq to object query.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: So what can be the alternative of this?

Comment: i am facing same issue due to usage .Split(' ')[0]. I fixed this problem from client side using  DataFormatString="{0: hh:mm tt}"

Comment: It can be fixed from server side by using .ToShortTimeString()  in LINQ

Comment: I've also had the same issue with using Split function, ended up removing it from Linq expression..

Answer (score 2):

Filter as much as you can on the server and then, what you can't on the client.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddYears(1);
var serverQuery = from s in dcDistrict.ScheduledReportStatus
    where s.SentDate >= startDate && s.SentDate < endDate
        && s.ReportConfigId.Equals(ConfigId)
        && s.Status.HasValue && s.Status.Value
    select s;
var clientQuery = from s in serverQuery
    where // whatever client side filtering
    select s;
```